# AWS Lambda error : net: dns lookup sometimes fails with "no such host" when there are too many open files

Tags: go, aws-lambda, tcp, file-descriptor

DB connection config:

```
c := sqlutil.DBConfig{
        UserName:           "user",
        UserPassword:       "DbPwd",
        Host:               "DbHost",
        Port:               "DbPort",
        DatabaseName:       "DbName",
        RdsPemFile:         "DbPemFile",
        UseSsl:             false,
        MaxIdleConns:       16,
        MaxOpenConns:       128,
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        CharsetType:        "utf8mb4",
    }
    nRetries := 10
    delay := 30
```

Http rest client

```
&RestClient{
        logger:     logger,
        scheme:     "https://",
        apiRootURL: apiRootURL,
        client: http.Client{
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                    Timeout: 30 * time.Second, //TCP Connect Timeout 30 Secs
                }).DialContext,
                MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 8,
                MaxIdleConns:        16,
            },
            Timeout: 600 * time.Second}, //Total Read Timeout 10 mins
    }
```

Lambda config file

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  function_name = var.function_name
  role          = data.aws_iam_role.lambda.arn
  handler       = var.handler
  timeout       = var.timeout
  runtime       = var.runtime
  memory_size   = var.memory_size
  kms_key_arn   = var.kms_key_arn
}
variable "timeout" {
  default = 300
}

variable "runtime" {
  default = "go1.x"
}

variable "memory_size" {
  default = 128
}

variable "reserved_concurrent_executions" {
  default = -1
}
```

Consumer :

```
resp, err = r.client.Do(req)  //req *http.Request, r *RestClient

    if err != nil {
        <return errorcode>
    }

    body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 { }
```

Above is my db connection config and https connection config.
I am making an api call (with the https rest client) sequentially for multiple times (2000-3000) using this connection and updating my db (created with the dbconfig).
but after making some api calls, we get an error of `net: dns lookup sometimes fails with "no such host" when there are too many open files`

The rest client connection is also closed after the required operation. [Do we need more info into this?]

I tried isolating the two calls and found that http client is the problem. after around 1000-2000 calls, we get the fd error.

I understand that each open connection is 1 file descriptor (henceforth mentioned as fd) and the max fd limit of aws lamda is intrinsically 1024.

How do I get around this issue with the confined parameters of the aws lambda ??

[lambda memory footprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF1Yh.png)

Comment: Connections to where? Can we see the full config file and Lambda code?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary have updated the description of the problem. Please let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please add the code that uses the HTTP client? I think connections are being left open.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, updated the question with the caller.

Comment: If your timeout is 10 minutes and you have 2000+ calls, of course it will error. Have you tried a much smaller timeout? 10 minutes is an insane value as a HTTP timeout.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @ErmiyaEskandary,
I tried reducing the time to 15 seconds, even 10 seconds.
But it is still failing .